# Blur event dimiss click event in Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a simple form with a text and a submit button like this

```
<label>Input something </label>
<input type="text" id="TextId" value="Whatever you input,it is wrong" />
 <div id="ErrorDiv"></div>
 <input type="submit" id="SubmitButton""/>
```

I attach a focusout event in the text box to show the mutiline message at ErrorDiv.
when I click button submit, onfocusout of the text execute first and it makes my button move out of its position And the Onclick Event won't be fired.

[fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/UgJL8/8/)

Any one can explain to me how can It happen and How can I fix it

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blur event is being fired before the click event. This is happening because a click event gets fired after the mouse button is released. The easiest way to make this work is to show the alert on the mousedown event instead of on the click event.

For example, use this

```
    $("#SubmitButton").live("mousedown", function() {
        alert("button click!");
    });
```

The above change worked for me in chrome on OS X, however you should be aware that there is some [controversy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6939306/should-blur-or-mousedown-fire-first) around this. A better solution would be to re-arrange your elements so that the validation messages don't push out the submit button.

Comment: FYI, I have some tricks: Using Css to make my button lay out at its position until click event occur.
http://jsfiddle.net/UgJL8/10/

Comment: This is an interesting approach, but...I would avoid applying styles in this way. It is not maintainable, and that is just one of the problems. I recommend that you change the layout if at all possible so that the problem is avoided. For example you could use the jQuery validation plugin (http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) and display the validation errors on the right side of the form, or even use a tooltip to display the errors like this (http://djpate.com/2010/11/16/using-jquery-validation-plugin-with-tooltips/). (you would have to call validate() on 'focusout' for each field)