# How to avoid pressing save button twice on an ExtJS grid that uses cell editing

Tags: javascript, extjs4, mouseevent

When using ExtJS grids for cell editing there can be an issue of having to click a button twice because the blur event for the editor (a textfield) gets called first and then the first button click event is for some reason no longer accessible.  How is it possible to avoid pressing a (save) button twice in this circumstance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid some bugs that manifested themselves using the other answer I extracted what I needed into it's own xtype as follows:

```
Ext.define('Predictive.view.ParamGridSaveButton', {
    extend: 'Ext.button.Button',
    alias: 'widget.paramGridSaveButton',

    onMouseDown: function() {
        Predictive.eventBus.fireEvent('dropdownSaveClicked', this);
        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

We leveraged the fact that mousedown should fire before blur; see: [Should blur or mousedown fire first?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6939306/34806) (and more than one other post albeit using jQuery).  ExtJS does not directly expose mousedown on it's button component, perhaps considering click enough, but it does implement an onMouseDown method and that is enough of an entry point.

See the toolbar definition below and particularly the last, "Save" button within the IIFE (immediately invoked function expression).  What I am doing is replacing the button instance's onMouseDown implementation with a version that is augmented using [Ext.function.createInterceptor](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.Function-method-createInterceptor).

In order to remain MVC friendly I could (and will) instead replace the entire function body with the firing of a single event that the controller will be listening for.  Hope this helps somebody and will be interested to see other suggested solutions either here or on [the Sencha forums](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?229023-Custom-CellEditor-CompleteEdit-on-blur)

```
dockedItems: [{
    xtype: 'toolbar',
    dock: 'top',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'Add Another'
    }]
},{
    xtype: 'toolbar',
    dock: 'bottom',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'tbfill'
    }, {
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'Cancel'
    }, (function() {
        var saveButton = Ext.create('Ext.button.Button', {
            text: 'Save'
        });

        saveButton.onMouseDown = Ext.Function.createInterceptor(saveButton.onMouseDown, function () {
            var gridValues = Ext.pluck(saveButton.up('grid').store.data.items, 'data');
            var paramTypeWindow = saveButton.up('window');
            var typeDetailCell = paramTypeWindow.typeDetailCell;

            paramTypeWindow.close();

            if (typeDetailCell.items.length === 0) {
                typeDetailCell.add({
                    xtype: 'textarea',
                    width: 375
                });
            }

            typeDetailCell.items.getAt(0).setValue(Ext.encode(gridValues));

        }, saveButton)

        return saveButton;
    })()]
}]
```